# Call activity direct from current activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Can i call second activity from current activity without use intent? and why use intent, why not call second activity direct from the first activity?.
What does intent do in android?

Comment: Read basics of Android. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Intent it's a mechanism for interaction between system components, like activity, broadcast receivers, services. What you mean under "call another activity"?

Comment: Can you talk with your friends without calling their number if they are very far from you? The same case is android. All activities are sleeping you need to invoke them by use of intents. So intent is like a phone call. This is the noobs reply. Read above basics of Android posted by @Rohit5k2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because to start any new Activity Android must have to go through the life cycle of an Activity. So it is necessary to use intent.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
you can't ,see this link android is designed in this way to launch another activity

Answer (score 0):

Intent says to Android you need open a new activity. Always when you need open a new Activity, you need "alert" the S.O before. Because of this we use Intent.
Activities doesn't work like a simple class, when we just instantiate.

This link will help you
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html